# Separate workspace per monitor in XFCE

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

I'm looking for a way of configuring two independent screens on my two physical monitors, either via XFCE's workspaces or separate X servers. The video card is integrated Intel:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

I've googled a lot of possible ways, but they're all pretty old and mostly outdated (for instance, use Xinerama, which is reportedly superseded by Xrandr), still haven't found a workable solution for multihead/multiworkspace setup.

The background: in the system there's one "real" monitor, and another that's only supposed to be displaying a specific window (so that user cannot drag windows onto it etc.) The OS is Xubuntu 18.04.

**N.B.:** this must be implemented using XFCE and Xfwm since the technology stack has been unambiguously defined by the architect.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but I've managed *solving* it differently. The workaround is to use one workspace for only second/third monitor and mark windows that should stay on the second screen as visible on all workspaces. This, obviously, only works if you plan to have some side notes on that monitor and is definitely far from perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of experiments I've managed to solve this using the `ZaphodHeads` Intel driver option mentioned in [this](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2015-October/057706.html) mail thread. The working configuration is:

```
# Put this in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-dualscreen.conf

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Intel0"
    Driver         "intel"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
    Screen         0
    Option         "MonitorDP" "DP1"
    Option         "ZaphodHeads" "DP1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Intel1"
    Driver         "intel"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
    Screen         1
    Option         "MonitorVGA" "VGA1"
    Option         "ZaphodHeads" "VGA1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "MonitorDP"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "MonitorVGA"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Option         "AutoServerLayout" "on"
    Device         "Intel0"
    Monitor        "MonitorDP"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth      24
        Modes      "1280x1024"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Option         "AutoServerLayout" "on"
    Device         "Intel1"
    Monitor        "MonitorVGA"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth      24
        Modes      "1280x1024"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Multihead"
    Option         "AutoServerLayout" "on"
    Screen         0  "Screen0"
    Screen         1  "Screen1"
EndSection
```

In this configuration the screen attached to DisplayPort (`DP1`) is primary (`DISPLAY=:0.0`) and one can use keyboard and mouse against it, whereas another display, connected to VGA (`VGA1`), is referred to as `DISPLAY=:0.1` and is unreachable with the input devices.